# Sidebar not working not sure why

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
```

I am trying to make a sidebar. Not sure why it is not working .Making a website and it is not working. I am a self-taught and I am doing better but this sidebar isnt working. I have tired to do everything to correct it but it didnt work.

```
    <div id="sidebar">

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="sidebar-btn">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
    </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3s/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    $(document).ready(function()
        $('#sidebar-btn').click(function(){
            $('#sidebar').addClass('visible');
        });


    </script>



        </div>


    </div>

</body>
</html>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3s/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
        <script>
            
        $(document).ready(function()
            $('#sidebar-btn').click(function(){
                $('#sidebar').addClass('visible');
            });
            
            
        </script>
    body{
     margin:0px
     padding:0px;
        font-family: "Helvetic Neue";
        
    }
    #sidebar{
     background:#151718;
     width:200px;
     height:100%;
     display:block;
     position:absolute;
     left:-200px;
     top:0px;
        transition:left 0.3s linear;

    }
    #sidebar.visible{
        left:0px;
        transition:left 0.3s linear; 
    }
    ul{ 
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }

    ul li{
        list-style:none;
    }
    ul li a{
        background:#1C1E1F;
        color:#ccc;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
        display: block;
        width:180px;
        padding: 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    #sidebar-btn{
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        width:20px;
        height:15px;
        cursor:pointer;
        margin:20px;
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        right:-60px;
    }
    #sidebar-btn span{
        height:1px;
        background:#111;
        margin-bottom:5px;
        display: block;
    }
    #sidebar-nth-child(2){
        width: 75%
    }
    <html>
    <head>
     <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sidebar">

       <ul>
        

    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          </ul>
                   <div id="sidebar-btn">
                       <span></span>
                       <span></span>
                       <span></span>
            </div>
           </div>
            
            <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3s/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
           <script>
             
            $(document).ready(function()
                $('#sidebar-btn').click(function(){
                $('#sidebar').addClass('visible');
                });
            
            
            </script>
            
            
            
                </div>
        
        
            </div>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 script tags inside body?

Comment: your ```$(document).ready(function()``` has no opening curly bracket and closing you should do ```$(document).ready(function(){ });```

Comment: You should really be using an IDE to better format your code and it would also mark your syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the opening `{` and closing `});` after `$(document).ready(function()`

This will also only show the sidebar. If you want the sidebar to open/close, change `$("#sidebar").addClass("visible");` to `$("#sidebar").toggleClass("visible");`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sidebar-btn").on("click", function() {
    $("#sidebar").addClass("visible");
    /* use this if you want to open/close the sidebar */
    /* $("#sidebar").toggleClass("visible"); */ 
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px padding:0px;
  font-family: "Helvetic Neue";
}

#sidebar {
  background: #151718;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -200px;
  top: 0px;
  transition: left 0.3s linear;
}

#sidebar.visible {
  left: 0px;
  transition: left 0.3s linear;
}

ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
  background: #1C1E1F;
  color: #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#sidebar-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: -60px;
}

#sidebar-btn span {
  height: 1px;
  background: #111;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
}

#sidebar-nth-child(2) {
  width: 75%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="sidebar-btn">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much that work. I was going back over the code and could not figure it out

Comment: @SushanneS you're welcome. What editor do you use to write your code? syntax highlighting can point that out for you. Visual Studio Code is probably the best free editor and it will tell you about errors like that. Codepen.io will also tell you. That's what I use answer questions here on stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing the document ready declaration and you are missing a curly brace as well - see below

```js
            
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#sidebar-btn').click(function(){
                $('#sidebar').addClass('visible');
            });
          })
```

```css
body{
     margin:0px
     padding:0px;
        font-family: "Helvetic Neue";
        
    }
    #sidebar{
     background:#151718;
     width:200px;
     height:100%;
     display:block;
     position:absolute;
     left:-200px;
     top:0px;
        transition:left 0.3s linear;

    }
    #sidebar.visible{
        left:0px;
        transition:left 0.3s linear; 
    }
    ul{ 
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }

    ul li{
        list-style:none;
    }
    ul li a{
        background:#1C1E1F;
        color:#ccc;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
        display: block;
        width:180px;
        padding: 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    #sidebar-btn{
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        width:20px;
        height:15px;
        cursor:pointer;
        margin:20px;
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        right:-60px;
    }
    #sidebar-btn span{
        height:1px;
        background:#111;
        margin-bottom:5px;
        display: block;
    }
    #sidebar-nth-child(2){
        width: 75%
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>

     <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sidebar">

       <ul>
        

    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          </ul>
                   <div id="sidebar-btn">
                       <span></span>
                       <span></span>
                       <span></span>
            </div>
           </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3s/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
        <script>
            
        $(document).ready(function()
            $('#sidebar-btn').click(function(){
                $('#sidebar').addClass('visible');
            });
            
            
        </script>
```

```css
    body{
     margin:0px
     padding:0px;
        font-family: "Helvetic Neue";
        
    }
    #sidebar{
     background:#151718;
     width:200px;
     height:100%;
     display:block;
     position:absolute;
     left:-200px;
     top:0px;
        transition:left 0.3s linear;

    }
    #sidebar.visible{
        left:0px;
        transition:left 0.3s linear; 
    }
    ul{ 
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }

    ul li{
        list-style:none;
    }
    ul li a{
        background:#1C1E1F;
        color:#ccc;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
        display: block;
        width:180px;
        padding: 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    #sidebar-btn{
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        width:20px;
        height:15px;
        cursor:pointer;
        margin:20px;
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        right:-60px;
    }
    #sidebar-btn span{
        height:1px;
        background:#111;
        margin-bottom:5px;
        display: block;
    }
    #sidebar-nth-child(2){
        width: 75%
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
     <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sidebar">

       <ul>
        

    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          </ul>
                   <div id="sidebar-btn">
                       <span></span>
                       <span></span>
                       <span></span>
            </div>
           </div>
            
            <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3s/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
           <script>
             
            $(document).ready(function()
                $('#sidebar-btn').click(function(){
                $('#sidebar').addClass('visible');
                });
            
            
            </script>
            
            
            
                </div>
        
        
            </div>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: I will that and see if it works. What is the best IDE to use?

Comment: I like Webstorm